# How to avoid to show a float: -0.0

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

I want to show my float number with just 1 digit and **avoid** to show this case **-0.0**.

My program is a C/C++ development for an Arduino board.

How can I do that?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages (particularly when it comes to I/O).  Please pick one!

Comment: Do you want to show the precision as one digit ? .

Comment: Yes I want to show a precision with one digit. It's ok for that, but it's just in this case with a float value equal for example at -0.000001, I want to show 0.0 and not -0.0

Comment: printf("%2.1f",var); should do.

Comment: storing and showing are different things. If you use printf for example you should use `printf("%.0f", myFloat);` to set the display precision to 0, so for example -0.001 would display as -0

Comment: "it's just in this case with a float value equal for example at -0.000001, I want to show 0.0" - for this situation we have the if statement. `if (myFloatValue < EPS) ...` where EPS is your chosen small quantity that you want to treat as "close enough" to zero

Comment: If x is your float value then use a conditional like if or ?: to force a 0.0 to print when you want it `printf("%.1f\n", (int)(x * 10) == 0 ? 0.0 : x);` Notice that if the quantity is negative then the printed result is supposed to be `-0.0` as you mentioned

Comment: std::cout << (value == 0.0 ? abs(value) : value)  << std::endl;

Comment: @Schepurin, neat but note that abs returns an integer type; use fabs to return a double. Benign here of course but could cause the OP trouble, especially if used in `printf` with an incompatible format specifier.

Comment: OP wants values in the range -0.05 < x <= -0.0 to appear as "0.0". It's the edge cases of -0.0 and near -0.05 (an inexact value) that will stress any solution.  Preconditioning `x` or its format before calling `printf()` is tricky.  Suggest a simple post-processing: `float x; char buf[50]; sprintf(buf, "%.1f", x); if (strcmp(buf, "-0.0")==0) strcpy(buf, "0.0"); printf("%s", buf);`

Answer (score 3):

(Applies to both C and C++).

IEEE754 floating point defines a **signed zero**. This is the effect you're observing here. One may obtain negative zero as the result of certain computations, for instance as the result of arithmetic underflow on a negative number, or `−1.0 * 0.0`, or simply as `−0.0`.

-0.0 is defined to equal 0.0.

One solution would be to analyse it as a special case: `x == -0.0 ? /*handle -0.0 and 0.0 here: e.g. ::fabs(x)*/ : /*non-zero cases here*/`.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: ah ! fabs(var),good answer .

Answer (score 1):

you can try printing out this way using the c ternary operator.

```
 printf("%2.1f",(f<0 &&f >-1)?-f:f);
```

here f is an floating point variable and if u get value of f as -0.0001 , the function will print out as 0.0 .

Comment: The number `-0.0` does not make `f < 0` true.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid showing the negative sign you will need to actually round of the number before displaying it since the +/- of a number is irrespective of the precision